# FileNotFoundError in Python Flask

Tags: flask, python-3.6

I am trying to run my Flask app.

I am not opening any files directly. Python 3.6. PyCharm IDE 2019.1.2.

```
application = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template', static_url_path='/static')
Talisman(application, content_security_policy=csp)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

This also does not work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

When I run it, I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6': '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6'
```

I repeat - I am not directly opening any files. This error is thrown when attempting to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question for two reasons:

- To answer it because I believe I found an edge case to this error.
- To start a thread specifically for when Flask throws this error.

**My solution:**

I was connected to public / a different WiFi than I normally connect to.

Once I connected to my personal WiFi, the program ran normally and did not throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Another reason this might happen:**

I reset some settings on my computer that resulted in Python 2 becoming the default version of Python.

Running the Flask app using python application.py resulted in this error being thrown.

Running Flask using python**3** application.py fixed the issue.